# Remote powershell call using Invoke-Command doesn't work from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, invoke-command

The following command works when called directly from powershell, but not when called within an ASP.NET application.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotesrv -ScriptBlock { 5 }
```

I suppose, there is some kind of user rights problem, but at this point I am stuck and don't know how to solve this.

The ASP.NET code looks as follows:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var rs = "-ComputerName remotesrv";
            powershell.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
            var script = String.Format("Invoke-Command {0} -scriptblock {{ 5 }}", rs);
            powershell.AddScript(script);

            powershell.InvocationStateChanged += delegate(object sender, PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.InvocationStateInfo.State == PSInvocationState.Completed)
                {
                    // Clean up
                }
            };

            var output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
            output.DataAdded += delegate(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
            {
                PSDataCollection<PSObject> myp = (PSDataCollection<PSObject>)sender;
                Collection<PSObject> results = myp.ReadAll();
                foreach (PSObject result in results)
                {
                    if (result.BaseObject is int)
                    {
                        // Do something in the database
                    }
                }
            };

            IAsyncResult asyncResult = powershell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
);
```

If I don't add `-ComputerName remotesrv`, the script is executed.

What do you need to do, to be able to call a powershell script remotely from an ASP.NET application?

Comment: show what you have in ASP.NET.

Comment: I added the code. However, it's working without `-ComputerName remotesrv`.

Comment: Does the account the code runs under (set up in IIS) have admin privileges on both the local machine and the remote machine.

Comment: It runs under the Default Pool Identity, which is a problem, I guess, but I don't know, what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you read through the [Powershell remoting requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847859.aspx) specifically the User Permission portion. By default, the account creating the connection must be an administrator on the remote machine. If your web application is running under an identity that is not an administrator on the remote machine, the connection will fail. Note that this is the default behaviour and can be changed by tweaking the [session configurations](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847817.aspx) on the remote machine.

Comment: I guess, I have to add a user using `Set-PSSessionConfiguration -name Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI`. But what user do I need to add? The following locations dialogue doesn't display the other servers in the network.

Comment: You need to add the account that the site is running in the context of. You may need to create a account, application pool, etc for the site and then add it.

Comment: But how do I add an account, that isn't displayed under locations? No account of the other server is available there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was change the user who  execute  IIS's application pool.
After set Enable-PsRemoting -Force and Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted, (perhaps  is better left ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned), invoke-command still doesn't work. 
Then I went to Task Manager, Process tab and look by w3wp.exe and the User that was executing that process was "DefaultAppPool", I guess that this user have not rights to remote access or execution on PowerShell. (Image shows Administrador because I already change it)

[image]

To change the user go to IIS Manager, in application groups, my site's application groups shows in Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity, Select the application pool and click Advanced Settings, in Process Model, select Identity and click the ellipsis (the button with the three dots). In Personal Account sets an Administrator account with username and password, reboot IIS.

[image]

If I look by Task Manager, iis user has changed